# Wedderburn Decomposition of Matrix Algebras in MATLAB/Octave

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, matlab, c-star-algebras, matrix-decomposition

Is there a MATLAB/Octave function/package that, given a subalgebra of matrices, will calculate the Wedderburn decomposition? That is, it will output a unitarily equivalent block diagonal form of the matrices? E.g., given generators

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\\1&1&1&1\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1&i&-1&-i\\1&i&-1&-i\\1&i&-1&-i\\1&i&-1&-i\end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\-i&-i&-i&-i\\-1&-1&-1&-1\\i&i&i&i\end{pmatrix},$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}1&i&-1&-i\\-i&1&i&-1\\-1&-i&1&i\\i&-1&-i&1\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}2&-1-i&0&-1+i\\-1+i&2&-1-i&0\\0&-1+i&2&-1-i\\-1-i&0&-1+i&2\end{pmatrix}$$

it would output (in some form) that this is isomorphic to $M_2\oplus (1_2\otimes M_1)$ and that the unitary that does this is $u=\frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}1&1&1&1\\1&i&-1&-i\\1&-1&1&-1\\1&-i&-1&i\end{pmatrix}$.

I found a few papers on algorithms to do this (e.g., [Maehara and Murota, 2010](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s13160-010-0007-8)) but I was hoping someone has already implemented the methods.

Comment: Just checking this http://www.misojiro.t.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~maehara/commdec/ linked from one of the authors' page http://www.prefield.com is not what you are looking for?